# Nativescript Vue on android not updating image in drawable folder

Tags: android, image, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I've added images to my drawable folder, namely, I've changed the image icon.png from the default to my custom image. I've also added a screen.png image

however when I try to load the image:
`<Image src="res://icon"></Image>`

I still see the old default icon.png image and when I change the image source to `screen` then I get `LOG from device Nexus 6P: Missing Image with resourceID: res://screen`

I am using the `tns preview` command and using the NS Playground and NS Preview apps.

When I try to use a different approach, by adding the image to the `assets/images/` folder, and refer to it as `<Image src="~/images/icon.png"></Image>` Then I get:

`LOG from device Nexus 6P: Error in reading bitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/images/icon.png (No such file or directory)`

Can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: Changes to drawable folder requires a rebuild. Preview command do not build the app, it's just a quick way to test simple code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went with adding the image to the `/assets/images` folder and referred to it as: `<Image src="~/assets/images/icon.png"></Image>`

Comment: You will have to build the application with `tns [run|build]` commands for changes on drawable folders to be effective.

Comment: Thank you , you saved me , it take more than one day to search this